# PHP proxy - return response in case of error

Tags: php

I use PHP as proxy (for JS XMLHttpRequest).

In the following code:

> handle = @fopen(...);
>
> if (!$handle)
>   {
>
> ,,,
>
> }

I want to return the response (header + body) from the server in case i enter the IF.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using cURL than `fopen`. Not only is it faster, but IIRC you have finer-grained control over the options.

Edit: It's been suggested that I give an example of how to use this. The best examples are within PHP's documentation - http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php This example is pretty close to what I think you're wanting to do. You'd need to change the CURLOPT_HEADER option to 1 or TRUE.

There are a ton of options you can use to customize how cURL behaves. This page will tell you everything: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

If you've got the time, I'd recommend skimming through the cURL documentation - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php It's a powerful extension and very useful.

Comment: not a bad idea, would be helpful to the OP if you were to show a code example as to how this would work using curl instead of fopen.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the HTTP status you think is appropriate when `fopen` fails, e.g.:

```
if (!$handle) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    // header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement says `if(!$handle)`, meaning "if fopen() fails".  If `fopen()` fails, you're not going to be able to read a response body or header.  The return value from `fopen()` is the only handle to the data coming back from the server.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of how to get the information using `error_get_last()` instead of `$handle`:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://www.google.com/doesntwork.html","r");
if (!$handle){
    $error = error_get_last();
    $m=array();
    $i = preg_match('/(HTTP\/1.[01]) ([0-9]+) (.*)/',$error['message'],$m);
    if($i){
        echo "HTTP version: ".$m[1]."<br>\n";
        echo "HTTP status: ".$m[2]."<br>\n";
        echo "HTTP message: ".$m[3]."<br>\n";
    }
} else {
    $output="";
    while(!feof($handle)){
        $output .= htmlspecialchars(fgets($handle, 1024));
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "fopen returned with result: $output<br>\n";
}
?>
```

As another user posted, you're better off using `fopen()` wrappers and/or cURL.  Also, you shouldn't suppress warnings/errors...remove the `@` symbol and fix any errors that come up.

Comment: This is no correct. I enter the if when the server return any Http error. http_response_header has data. I just don't understand hot to get the body of the response and how to pass headers and body to the client

Comment: If you're able to make a connection to the server, `$handle` won't be set to `FALSE`.  `fopen()` only fails if the connection cannot be established.  Once it is established, `fopen()` should not return `FALSE`.

Comment: Again, in my case i do enter the if (fopen fails). http_response_headers[0] holds the correct error code from the server. Connection to server did establish